# Countable set example

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Another crazy question.

Is this a countable set;
$$A = \{-4, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$$

I think it is. But my teacher says it isn’t due to the concept 
, he says, is of one to one mapping with a some subset of natural number. Since some elements there contain non - $\Bbb N$ elements.

From what I know, a countable set is either a finite set, or a set with the same cardinality with some subset of $\mathbb N$, which make me think it is.

Comment: Although this is nothing but a matter of definition, I must say that you are right according to the most widely accepted definition for countability.

Comment: To be clear, the nature of the elements in $A$ is irrelevant.  Most people would say that any finite set is countable, regardless of the elements in the set.  In particular, your set is certainly countable.

Comment: Sometimes we see the term "countably infinite" to emphasize that we exclude finite sets.  On the other hand, sometimes you see two definitions, "countable" and "denumerable", one of which (I don't remember which) allows finite but the other doesn't.  So... check the definition in the book you are using!

Comment: Your teacher seems to have a totally misconceived idea of what countable means. It is absolutely irrelevant whether or not $\mathbb{N}$ contains 0. Ask the teach whether the set $\{apple,pear\}$ is countable!

Comment: That’s what I thought too, but classmates were like ??? ‍♂️

Comment: The teacher needs to be corrected by you in front of the class.

Comment: Noted @WilliamElliot

Comment: @PyrJames  Please let us know how he accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers.

Just verify that $f: A \to \{1, \ldots, 8 \}$

$$f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=4, f(4)=5, f(-4)=6, f(-2)=7, f(-1)=8 $$

is a bijection and you are done.

p/s: Of course, all finite set are countable.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and what your teacher says (at least as you have represented it) is wrong.  A countable set can have elements that are not in $\mathbb{N}$; you just need the set to have a bijection to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (which does not need to be the identity map!).  In other words, whether a set is countable depends only on *how many* elements it has, not what those elements are.